# Is there something wrong in editing too much?

Tags: discussion, edits

I love spending time refreshing the newest questions, and taking a look at some of them I consider interesting, and some others I think I can answer.

Lots of time I see code badly indented, misspelled words, some grammatical problems, etc...

**Is it bad to edit a question every time I see one of those?**

I have more than 80 edited questions, but I do not have permission to edit them. Every time I edit one, a moderator must accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing wrong at all. Your edits in general look good, and your [record](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/39817) (91 edits approved, of 92 submitted) speak to that.

You're making the world a better place (in a small way). Well-phrased questions lead to better answers. You'll get blowback at some point - someone will be unhappy with any changes at all to their prose, and will comment/downvote you. Understand that the community as a whole appreciates the effort.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that link existed ;) Is there a way to know which one was rejected?

Comment: @Oscar: not that I can see.

Comment: Is there a way to know what percent of my edits were accepted before I got the edit privilege?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: Dunno. I would have expected to see suggested edits on the [oldest page of your revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/618728/mr-wizard?tab=activity#apage_13-afilter_revisions), but I don't see any. If you're really curious, try to find a post you edited before you got the edit priv, look at its revision history, and click the *suggested edit* link.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges). The [Edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) privilege will be available to you when you reach 2,000 reputation points. After that, your edits will no longer need approval.

You also earn 2 reputation points for every approved edit (up to 1,000 reputation points earned this way or until you go past 2,000 rep total, whichever comes first), so keep those good edits coming!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that, but I just wanted to know if is okay editting the way I'm doing. Don't know. Maybe moderators are seeing too much edit requests comming from me :/

Comment: @Oscar You're clearly making good edits. Keep that up. Thanks for helping raise the quality of questions and answers. :)

Comment: @Oscar: Look at the [top editor](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) page. People do several orders of magnitudes more edits than you. You've got a ways to catch up. :)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta You're totally right ;)